# Generating heat maps for eye tracking data

Tags: python, r, matlab, heatmap

I have a dataset from Tobii Eyetracker.
The dataset looks like this after cetain manipulations

```
timestamp      xposition      yposition
```

I used python for collecting the data. The data was recoreded while the participant was looking at the monitor. I want to generate heatmaps for the size of the monitor.

> Later I also want to make an image and overlay this heatmap.

I want to use R to generate heatmaps.
What is the algorithm to do this or is there is plugin to directly feed my dataset as input?

**Experiment Setup:**

1. The time is relative time: 100,100.02,100.04,100.06..and so on
   incrementing in the order of .02 seconds
2. The xPosition and yPosition is in Centimeter. From the centre of the monitor.
3. The background image will be split into 10 row 6 column of square boxes with size 3.4cm each
4. size of the monitor resolution used is 1920x1080 exact [MonitorUsed](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824009300)

**The code I ran with error:**
after exporting using dlmwrite in matlab, i used the GUI in R Studio to load the variables and did the following:

```
> xPos = myfile[1:278,1]
> yPos = myfile[1:278,2]
> breaks.x <- seq(-23.5, 23.5, length.out = 3.4)
> breaks.y <- seq(-14.1, 14.1, length.out = 3.4)
> int.x <- findInterval(xPos, breaks.x)
> int.y <- findInterval(yPos, breaks.y)
> tb <- table(int.x, int.y)
> image(breaks.x, breaks.y, tb, las=1)
Error in image.default(breaks.x, breaks.y, tb, las = 1) : 
  dimensions of z are not length(x)(-1) times length(y)(-1)
```

i did it between - to + 23.5 in the x and - to + 14.1 in y so that i matched with the points i generated while do the experiment. The images where plotted only in this region.

[Dataset](http://blog.southpaw.in/?wpdmact=process&did=My5ob3RsaW5r)

Comment: Using table() function available both in matlab and r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all let's generate some data

```
# Set RNG seed for reproducibility 
set.seed(12345) 

times <- seq(as.POSIXct("2014-09-08 14:00:00"), 
             as.POSIXct("2014-09-08 16:00:00"), 5)
pos.x <- runif(length(times), 0, 1024)
pos.y <- runif(length(times), 0, 768)
```

Now we can use `findInterval` to map each x,y pair to a specific interval, which we define in `breaks.x` and `breaks.y`. In this case I used a 20x20 grid, but obviously you can change that at will.
We then use `table` to generate a contingency table which will be our "position matrix".

```
breaks.x <- seq(0, 1024, length.out = 20)
breaks.y <- seq(0, 768, length.out = 20)
int.x <- findInterval(pos.x, breaks.x)
int.y <- findInterval(pos.y, breaks.y)

# See below for explanation
int.x <- factor(int.x, levels=1:20)
int.y <- factor(int.y, levels=1:20)

tb <- table(int.x, int.y)
```

Finally, draw the heatmap

```
image(breaks.x, breaks.y, tb, las=1)
```

Note: the two `factor` calls are necessary because `table` will otherwise ignore intervals where no data point is present. Converting to a factor effectively forces table to output values even in those slots that have no values in it.

Comment: @arkv: well, since I am not actually using time for the heatmap, I don't see the problem there... Unless you want something else, then please edit your question to be more specific

Comment: I see now that time is not used. there are other bits that i have edited in the question

Comment: I want to know if the reading in cm will affect in overlaying backgroud image?

Comment: Units do not really matter, you'll just have to scale everything as needed.

Comment: after exporting from matlab using dlmwrite and loading using the GUI in R. I did the following

> xPos = myfile[1:278,1]

> yPos = myfile[1:278,2]

> breaks.x <- seq(-23.5, 23.5, length.out = 3.4)

> breaks.y <- seq(-14.1, 14.1, length.out = 3.4)
> int.x <- findInterval(xPos, breaks.x)
> int.y <- findInterval(yPos, breaks.y)
> tb <- table(int.x, int.y)
> image(breaks.x, breaks.y, tb, las=1)
Error in image.default(breaks.x, breaks.y, tb, las = 1) : 
  dimensions of z are not length(x)(-1) times length(y)(-1)

Comment: try just `image(tb)` for a start. My guess is that there are empty position that `table` does not return (the problem should be bypassed by maybe converting the breaks into factors?). It's a bit difficult to tell without having the data though...

Comment: added the data set that I was using. Please see if it helps anyway?

Comment: image(tb) works but as you mentioned it doesn't give a output that would be desired

Comment: Two errors in your code: 1) the `length.out` parameter of `seq` specifies the length of the output vector, so you should set it to 6 for x and 10 for y as you have a 6x10 grid. (please read `?seq` for details). 2) your y data is not in [-14.1, 14.1] (range is [-15.7, 15.1]), so either pre-filter it or use an appropriate range. After changing these two things I get the correct plot

Comment: See code here: http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=gr1c5J6A&version=2 (press the green "Run code" button on the bottom to plot the graph).

Comment: your code totally works and I cant get it to work for a different dimension. like interchanging the 6 and 10 for y and x respectively
i get error Dimension of z is not length(x)(-1) times length(y)(-1)

Comment: @akrv you are right, I updated the code.